# Tcl variable interact in different namespace, how to fix

Tags: namespaces, tcl

In tcl, I need to source some files, file1, file2, file3,.... fileN, I create each namespace for each file, but the var set in each namespace will impact other namespace's var

below is my code:

```
proc source_file { args } {
global i 
  namespace eval NC{$i} {
   uplevel #0 [list source [uplevel 1 {set args}]]
  }
 incr i
}
set i 1
set A 123
source_file file1.tcl
source_file file2.tcl
```

file1.tcl:

```
set A 456;
puts $A
```

file2.tcl:

```
puts $A
```

I expect file2.tcl's puts will print 123, but it print 456, what's my code error?

Comment: You are missing a closing square bracket for the "list" command

Comment: Just to point out, a simpler way to do this is just: `namespace eval NC{[incr i]} [list source file1.tcl]; namespace eval NC{[incr i]} [list source file2.tcl]`.  Though I'm not sure the namespace names are what you expect, this example will create two namespaces: `NC{1}` and `NC{2}` (ie. the braces are just literal characters in the string)

Comment: Ogilvie, A is level 0 var can be access/modify  in NC1 and NC2, escape NC1 and NC2, A should keep 456 as original level 0 value

Comment: I try with namespace, use up level way, but level 0’s A will be modify in namespace even escape the nc1 or nc2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`uplevel #0` is almost the same as doing `namespace eval ::`; the code argument runs in the global namespace. (The difference is in how they manage the stack; most code won't care about that difference.) That means both files are running in the *same* namespace, the global one.

In Tcl 8, you would need the file to properly say:

```
variable A 456
puts $A
```

To get the variable to be in the right namespace, and you need to invoke the file with:

```
uplevel "#0" [list namespace eval $ns [list source $filename]]
# I put #0 in quotes just to defeat the syntax highlighter here
```

assuming you put the namespace and filename in the right local variables, of course.

---

In Tcl 9, resolution is tweaked. That will break this code more and in several places, but in ways that should fix more bugs than it makes...